# C# Unable to Post JSON Data to Web Server

Tags: c#, json

Im trying to update a webservice. When retrieving the data, the data is received as JSON and this is fine. However I'm unable to update the web server. Below is the response I get when I pull data successfully.

```
{personaId: 1744648419, userName: "Test User 1", userAbbr: "TSTU1", Male: 1, Female: 0, vcredits: 18572,…}
accountCreatedPlatformName: "PC"
actives: [{id: 249147533520, timestamp: 1454819773, LocationID: "ID42331", active: true, assetId: 62,…},…]
bidTokens: {}
userAbbr: "TSTU1"
userName: "Test User 1"
vcredits: 18572
currencies: [{name: "VMONEY", funds: 18572, finalFunds: 18572}, {name: "USER_AWARDS", funds: 0, finalFunds: 0},…]
0: {name: "VMONEY", funds: 18572, finalFunds: 18572}
finalFunds: 18572
funds: 18572
name: "VMONEY"
1: {name: "USER_AWARDS", funds: 0, finalFunds: 0}
finalFunds: 0
funds: 0
name: "USER_AWARDS"
2: {name: "USER_TOKEN", funds: 0, finalFunds: 0}
finalFunds: 0
funds: 0
name: "USER_TOKEN"
divisionBusiness: 3
divisionInterstate: 4
Male: 1
established: "1454819773"
feature: {specials: 0}
Female: 0
personaId: 1744648419
personaName: "TestUser1"
purchased: false
reliability: {reliability: 125, daysActive: 44, daysInactive: 42, daysUnfinishedTime: 0}
seasonTicket: false
accountList: {account: [,…], activeAccId: 3}
cards: 6
unassignedItemSize: 0
unopenedAccounts: {preOrderAcc: 0, recoveredAcc: 0}
pointsWon: 32
```

I only want to update the following section either one of them or all of them depending on the information provided.

```
vcredits: 18572
currencies: [{name: "VMONEY", funds: 18572, finalFunds: 18572}, {name: "USER_AWARDS", funds: 0, finalFunds: 0},…]
0: {name: "VMONEY", funds: 18572, finalFunds: 18572}
finalFunds: 18572
funds: 18572
name: "VMONEY"
1: {name: "USER_AWARDS", funds: 0, finalFunds: 0}
finalFunds: 0
funds: 0
name: "USER_AWARDS"
2: {name: "USER_TOKEN", funds: 0, finalFunds: 0}
finalFunds: 0
funds: 0
name: "USER_TOKEN"
```

Below is the code I'm using to update

private CreditsResponse vcredits;

```
    public async Task<CreditsResponse> PerformRequestAsync()
    {

        vcredits = new CreditsResponse();

        List<Currency> vmoney = new List<Currency>();
        Currency userCoins = new Currency();
        userCoins.Name = "VMONEY";
        userCoins.FinalFunds = 20000;
        userCoins.Funds = 20000;

        vmoney.Add(userCoins);

        vcredits.Currencies = vmoney;
        vcredits.Credits = 20000;

        var vMoneyContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vcredits);
        HttpContent content = new StringContent(vMoneyContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        AddMethodOverrideHeader(HttpMethod.Post);
        AddCommonHeaders();

        var addvCeditsResponseMessage = await HttpClient
            .PostAsync(string.Format(Resources.Home + Resources.Credits), content)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);

        return await Deserialize<CreditsResponse>(addvCeditsResponseMessage);

    }
```

I keep getting a 404 and not sure why. Any help on this would be great.

Comment: Try to put the url without variables to see if this can come from that point

Comment: Thanks for the response. Tried just using the URL but still the same error. Could the issue be in the formatting?

Comment: All seems to be correct, the vcredits object  is the same as in the backend?

Answer (score 0):

404 means it didn't found the URL you are trying to request to.

I usually have this problem when I have configured POST on the API but do a GET or when I type the endpoint name wrongly (either on client or server side).

Have you validated your API Endpoint and request method?

Comment: The get works fine no issues on the get. The endpoint name is correct and have verified it several times.

Comment: Ok I can post now. However the post isn't updating my results on the website.

Comment: Are you refreshing the results after updating?

Comment: How would you refresh it after updating. I get a json code of 460. Its not a just a page refresh is it?